# How do I make a theme persist even after the page is refreshed?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, frontend, web-frontend

I'm writing HTML/CSS/JavaScript code and want a function or solution so that **when the user refreshes the page the theme stays the same.**

Preferably a simple solution because I am a beginner in this field.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I do not know how you are applying the theme but what you could do is to store
the current theme in the localstorage and read it when the page has loaded.

```
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  let theme = localStorage.getItem("theme");
  if (theme === "dark") {
    // insert how you apply your theme
  } else {
    // apply other theme
  }
});
```

To store a theme you would then want to use the setItem method.

```
localStorage.setItem("theme", "your value goes here")
```

Hope this is what you were looking for.